# How do I pause a for cicle (loop) to insert some values in Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, cin

All I want is to hold the FOR circle while the user insert a name in a array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
char nomes[]={};
int numpessoas;
int main() {
    cout << "Quantas pessoas queres registar?\n";
    pede:
    cin >> numpessoas;
    if (numpessoas < 1) {
        goto pede;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i<= numpessoas; i++){
            cout << i << "º nome\n";
            cin << nomes[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it in a few lines?

Comment: this code will crash because you don't allocate memory for `nomes[]`.

Comment: I would use a simple loop instead.

Comment: Though your program is invalid and shall not be compiled I have not understood your question. The loop will be executed (provided that the program will be written correctly) until you will enter all elements of the array.

Comment: Yes us can use a while loop :) while (numpessosas < 1){ cin >> numpessosas} just make sure you initialize numpessosas = 0 at the top.

Comment: We typically call them "for loops", not "for circles" :)

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations and correct terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the term is not "circle", it's "loop", you have a "for loop".

Secondly, your declaration of `nomes` try to declare an array of size zero. This is not allowed in plain C++ and should give you a compilation error. It is, however, an extension in some compilers. The problem with that is that you then have undefined behavior when you try to assign to entries in this zero-sized array, as all assignments will write outside of the array bounds.

Thirdly, arrays are indexed from zero to size-1, so either you have to change your `for` loop to count from `0` to `i< numpessoas`, or you have to use `i - 1` when indexing the array.

You also are using the wrong operator for the input, `<<` is the *output* operator. Since you are using the wrong operator (you don't get an error or at least a warning for this?) the loop will not stop waiting for input.

---

Since you are programming in C++, I highly advise you to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: There is no undefined behaviour. The program will not be simply compiled.

Comment: [Vlad's right](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0710bc59aeff146); zero-sized arrays are an extension on certain implementations but they are banned in standard C++ and they do not compile for me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [compiles just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbddbc8a08287335) if you drop the warning flags

Comment: @TemplateRex: Doesn't mean it's valid. Doesn't mean it's UB.

Comment: @TemplateRex of course if you enable the extensions, the code that uses the extensions compiles.

Comment: Fascinating, if you enable extensions you can use extensions? Tell me more.

Comment: @JBentley well it kind of answers it: once all the other problems are solved, the reason why this would not block to wait for input is because of the use of the wrong operator (which I guess was the problem the OP noticed).

Comment: @Hulk: Yep that bit forms the answer. +1 if this were a bit more prominent and the statement about `nomes` fixed.